# How to get name of current gedit document with python?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk3, gedit, gedit-plugin

I'm writing a gedit plugin for gtk3.  Is there an easy way to get the name of the current document using python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very good [tutorial on writing gedit 3 plugins](https://web.archive.org/web/20150216231821/http://www.micahcarrick.com/writing-plugins-for-gedit-3-in-python.html). The example #3 does what you want: connect to a "open new tab" signal and write the document name.

And here you have the complete [Gedit API reference](http://developer-old.gnome.org/gedit/stable/).

```python
handler_id = self.window.connect("tab-added", self.on_tab_added)

(...)

def on_tab_added(self, window, tab, data=None):
    document = tab.get_document()
    print "'%s' has been added." % document.get_short_name_for_display()
    print "New file's path: %s" % document.get_uri_for_display()
```

Comment: Cheers.   It would be nice if they had a reference in python as it would be clearer to see as a python developer.

Comment: Get used to read the C documentation, is the best documented. And, as the python binding is automatically generated, it's very easy to "translate" from C to python: **(C)** gedit_document_goto_line (doc,line) -> **(python)** doc.goto_line (line)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd improve your chances of getting an answer by asking on the [gedit mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gedit-list/).

There's also a [GEdit python plugin howto](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo) on the GNOME wiki.